# C++: How can I find out the layout/addresses of the v-table?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, vtable

I'd like to try and have a look at how my compiler has arranged the v-table for a polymorphic class- see the function addresses etc. What would be the best way to do this in C++ code?

For example, if I override the parent class' method the function address should be an address within the child class. If I hadnt overridden, the function address would have been an address in the parent class.

Comment: There isn't a good way to do this that isn't platform & compiler specific. You're better off looking at the assembly generated.

Comment: You mean you want to access this information in runtime using C++, or are you asking for info on how to deduce it by looking at the generated assembly?

Comment: @Groo run-time would be fine. I just want to see how the v-table has been created.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/942922-virtual-pointer-accessing-vtable-class-inside-program)

Comment: @JonesV excellent! I think thats what I wanted: "//*vptr is address of first virtual function in VTABLE viz. display()"

Comment: @user997112: to see how the v-table has been created, look at the binary. the vtable is in there, it is not created at runtime.

Comment: @PlasmaHH could you elaborate on "look at the binary". What would I use to look at it and what would I be looking for?

Comment: @user997112 The debugger can show it (at least gdb can).

Comment: @user997112: That would entirely depend on your platform. in the last resource, its always a hexeditor.

Comment: @user997112: it's platform (or compiler) specific. I don't see why the object pointer would point directly to the vtable, opposed to a (say) offset from a fixed address. [In that link by JonesV](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/942922-virtual-pointer-accessing-vtable-class-inside-program) I also don't get the "pointer (...) 2 bytes" part. 16-bit addressing? I am pretty sure you'll have some trial and error while invoking those function pointer until you get the actual one.

Comment: I would recommend that you go to *the source* and read the documentation on how it is done. The ABI for windows is not publicly available, but you can google for "Itanium C++ ABI" to get the ABI used by gcc in linux (and some other compilers/operating systems). The first thing that you will notice is that there is far more complexity than you might be expecting and clearly more than the link that was provided. Not an easy read, but an interesting one. Alternatively you can get a copy of *The C++ Object Model* that describes in simple terms this and other concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get address of virtual function or some else information about vmt without hacks.
In most case class internally look like this structure:

```
struct ClassInternal
{
   void* vmt; // this field generate and add by compile automatically if class need vmt
   int field0;
   ...
};
```

Some compilers sort address functions in VMT in order that defined in headers (but it can be change in any time be carefully), first will be parent class functions then childs.